# Auto complete extender issue in ASP page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a text box in a web page for inputting the name and an auto complete extender attached to the text box which displays similar set of names which are in the database.

Here is my problem with an example to understand it better. Say I am searching for “robert shandwick” and as soon as I start typing the letter “R”, I get a list of names which begin with R are shown as suggestion. Next as we all know how auto complete extender works; it displays similar names from the database. All good till this point. But once if the user enters “robert” manually without selecting from the suggestions shown and hits space and then starts typing the next part of the name i.e. “shandwick”, a list of names which begin with “S” starts displaying, like “Sam Anderson”. I don’t want this to happen.

My database has First name and Last name as two different columns and the query for auto complete extender is

```
Select * from profiles WHERE FirstName+LastName like '" + InputText + "%'
```

I know that there needs to be something changed in the query, just unable to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can resolve your problem

```
Select * from profiles WHERE IsNull(FirstName,'') + ' ' + Isnull(LastName,'') like '" + InputText + "%'
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved it.. It was not the query, i mentioned space to be one of the delimiter and so it was taking it to be a new word on a whole after space.